# split string by rows

Tags: php, regex, split, line-endings

I have a string like so:

```
diverr_daily_report_2013-10-21_02:00:48_diverr_users_20_10_2013csv.csv
diverr_daily_report_2013-10-22_09:10:02_diverr_users_21_10_2013csv.csv
```

and i want to split it into elements.

output should look like:

```
[0]diverr_daily_report_2013-10-21_02:00:48_diverr_users_20_10_2013csv.csv
[1]diverr_daily_report_2013-10-22_09:10:02_diverr_users_21_10_2013csv.csv
```

i was thinking to use the first and last word as a needle(they never chnage) : "diverr,csv"

what is a good way of doing this?
thanks

Comment: Is splitting by lines not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split it by end-of-line:

```
$result = explode("\r\n", $your_string);
```

or if Unix, then:

```
$result = explode("\n", $your_string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
$array = explode("\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a another solution

```
$lines = preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $string );
```